# Daily reputation limit kicked in at 204 points?

Tags: bug, daily-reputation-limit

I just hit the daily reputation limit, yet for some reason it kicked in at an odd value. I believe the limit is 200 points earned from upvotes, however I have also been given an additional 4 points for... a reason I'm not sure of?

[image]

Here is a link to my itemised rep history for today: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NsXDR.png

This is not the first occurence of this issue I've had either, although I can't find the specific day it occurred while trawling back through my rep history.

Is this a bug in the limit calculation?

*Edit*

I just got given another single point too:

[image]

All very odd.

*Edit #2*

To add to the strange behaviour, overnight the erroneous 4 points were removed - which was correct. However I then received 6 points from another upvote later on. So now the total is 6 points out.

Also, my total shown in the banner is 158,106, yet the itemised [/repuation](https://stackoverflow.com/reputation) listing says I should have 158,100 - which is the correct value.

Something is still definitely not right.

Comment: Accepted answers don't count in for the rep limit of 200.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I didn't count them when totalling my points.

Comment: You may have lost 4 reputation today for some reason or another, which put you 4 rep below the cap, this was then compensated with an upvote.

Comment: @Cerbrus I though the same, but I have not  been downvoted.

Comment: There's nothing to be found in your rep graph / list on your profile?

Comment: No. I added a link to an image of it to the question

Comment: 3 downvotes and one upvote on the CSS or jquery post.

Comment: @Braiam I'm not sure where you're getting that, as I can't see any DVs today. Even if it was - 3 DVs = 6 points, not 4

Comment: @HansPassant I only donvoted 2 - and they were both removed: https://i.imgur.com/sev5Ab3.png

Comment: And just to make it that little more weird - I just got another single point: http://i.imgur.com/jLTEPrY.png

Comment: Well, just check your [/reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/reputation) audit.

Comment: Thanks for that link, I wasn't aware of it. According to that my rep is `158090`, so the 4 extra points do seem a mistake in the calc

Comment: 7 accepted answers: 7*15 = 105.  
Yor total change: 200 + 105 = 305.

Comment: @Qwertiy that matches what I totalled up too - I'm still not sure where the additional 4 points is coming from. Although it gets weirder, as overnight the 4 points were removed and 6 points were added.